# Error in JAVA when checking a user roles if the user does not have any roles in DB

Tags: java, xpages

I'm processing to see if the current user has a specific role or roles. The issue is that is the user has a role (even if it not one I'm checking for) all works well. However, if the user has no roles the check for the users roles throws a NUllPointerException. The code is:

```
Database appDB = this.getAppDB();
if (appDB == null) {
    if (debug) System.out.println("App DB is Null " );
}else{
    if (debug) System.out.println("App DB is Not Null " );
}
try{
    if (debug) System.out.println("WFS*** get roles");
    roles = appDB.getACL().getEntry(fullUser).getRoles();
    if (debug) System.out.println("Got User Roles  " );
}catch(NotesException e){
    roles.clear();
    if (debug) System.out.println("User Roles Null " ); 
}
```

the message "WFS*** get roles" displays in the log the variable fullUser is correct because it works when the user has roles in the appDB.
Not sure why the catch is not trapping the error, and why there is an error rather than just returning an Empty Vector.

Comment: Please add the stack dump.

Comment: @mbmast Exception is swallowed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `database.queryAccessRoles(userName)` - that should work regardless of whether the user has any roles or (as is probably the problem here) a named entry in the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure why the catch is not trapping the error...

Because you call clear() on null object in catch block. If assignment of `roles` object fails, it is still null, and you can not call a method on it.

Few improvement suggestions:

- always use `var` for your variables
- do not swallow exceptions
- do not make cascade calls (especially when something can get wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I bet your NullPointerException occurs when you call

```
roles.clear();
```

Which means and exception is being thrown when you try to query the user's roles.

Try doing:

```
if(roles!=null){
    roles.clear();
}
```

Hope it helps!